# How to make a model show up in the admin-section, in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python.

Currently, I am creating a website for weightlifting. Below is a simple model, with a lifter and results:

```
class Lifter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1);
    person_photo = models.CharField(max_length=1000);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.gender

class Results(models.Model):
    lifter = models.ForeignKey(Lifter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=0);
```

In the same app, there is a file called admin.py where I wrote:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Lifter

admin.site.register(Lifter)
```

Unfortunately, when I log into the admin-panel, there is no lifter-model to be seen. I have made sure to create the admin as a super-user, so the permissions should be there. In addition to this, the "usermanagement"-app (where the Lifter-model is stored) , has been added to settings.py in the main app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'athlitikos',
    'usermanagement',
]
```

Does anyone know what I should change to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Restart your server and then try

Comment: Thank you! I will try that now

Comment: or maybe try to unregister and then again register in admin.py

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that "simple"

Comment: anytime man... if this helped you can always upvote and accept answer  :)

Comment: done, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine to me

***try to unregister and then again register in admin.py***